# rubyからgetやpostを行う方法

Tags: ruby

rubyで任意のURLに対してpostやgetなどでパラメータを投げるにはどうしたらよいのでしょうか

Answer (score 2):

HTTP Client ライブラリを使うと簡単にできます。
HTTP Client ライブラリの実装は幾つかあり、以下の物が有名です。

[rest-client](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client)
[faraday](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday)
[httpclient](https://github.com/nahi/httpclient)

githubでは上から順に、スターの数が多いです。
使い方は、githubのページを参照するか、Googleで検索すると幾つか出てきます。

Answer (score 2):

たいていの用途には[net/http](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.2.0/library/open=2duri.html)か、GET限定であれば[open-uri](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.2.0/library/open=2duri.html)でよいでしょう。いずれもruby本体の添付ライブラリなのでrubyが入っている環境では間違いなく使えます。

標準ライブラリでは不都合がある、という前提での質問なら、どういう目的で何をしたいのか、その用途には標準ライブラリではどういう点が不都合なのか、を追記してもらえればよりよい回答が得られると思います。

Answer (score 0):

Rubyをつい最近はじめた者ですが、net/http内の
Net::HTTP
Net::HTTP::Post
Net::HTTP::Get
あたりでできるかとおもいます。

他の言語で同様の実装経験があれば、別の方がシェアされているリンクと検索してでてくるTIPSを参考にして比較的簡単に実装できると思います。

以下は私の書いたコードで、同一メソッド内でPOST/GETを切り替えて外部URL（この場合PayPal APIですが）にパラメータを渡して結果を取得しています。

https://github.com/benzookapi/PayPalRubyDemo/blob/master/app/models/pp_rest.rb#L38

（エラーハンドリングはちゃんとしてないですが）